# how to deal with a mounted EBS volume during URL swap?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use EBS volume as a storage of data (Lucene index, in my case). I mount this 50Gb volume to an instance from Java application, right after initialization. Every time an environment is started my web app attached the EBS volume to the EC2 instance it is running on, mounts the disc, and starts using the data there (for read **and** write). Everything works fine.

Now I'm trying to implement URL swap mechanism, which means that I will start a new environment every time I want to re-deploy the application. But the EBS volume will still be attached to the old environment. The conflict is obvious.

I don't know how this can be possibly resolved. Any ideas?

(I posted this question already to [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=99408), but didn't get any reasonable answer).

Comment: It's not clear to me what 'url swap mechanism' is or what you mean by a 'new environment'

Comment: see this article about URL swapping in ElasticBeansTalk: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/06/configuration-persistence-and-support-for-url-swapping-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found so far is to have an extra EC2 instance with the EBS volume attached, and shared through NFS among running EBT nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure this answers it:

You could snapshot the volume and create new one off of it and attach the new volume (based off the snapshot) to the new server.

Or, you could rsync the data over the network to your new volume.

But by using the AWS API you could snapshot old volume, create new volume, mount to new server.